# Trying to position Flutter List to bottom of screen

Tags: list, stack

I'm trying to position a List (puzzlePieces) at the bottom of the container on the screen. I've tried various alignment and position options, but most widget children do not accept a List. I  would also like to keep the puzzle pieces from being able to be moved out of the container and off of the screen. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
  child: Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
    child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: puzzlePieces),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Align' to bottom center you list.eg-

```
    child: Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border: new Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
             child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
               new Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: puzzlePieces),
       ] ),
      ),
)
```